Regarding Multitrip using OR tools
I'm currently working in a vrp model with timewindows and pickup facility. I want to enable multitrip for a vehicle. Lets say, each vehicle has maximum working hours. Within that it can do multitrip. After each delivery it will come back to depot and go for another delivery until it's maximum working hours. This is what I have developed till now:
Vehicle Data:

Order Data:

data is a class object. Inside data multiple dictionary are available. performmilkruns is a multitrip.
'''
def createCtForWaitingAndEndTime(data, routing, serviceCallBackIndices):
"""Adds waiting time and end time constraint for vehicles."""
maxEndTimeList = \
    data.vehicle.maxEndTimeList[data.iterStartIndex:data.iterEndIndex]

if data.parameters.performMilkRuns:
    slack = max(maxEndTimeList)
else:
    slack = data.parameters.maxWaiting

routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleTransitAndCapacity(serviceCallBackIndices,
                                                  slack, maxEndTimeList,
                                                  False,
                                                  constants.TIME_DIMENSION)
timeDimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(constants.TIME_DIMENSION)
for vehicleId in range(data.iterStartIndex, data.iterEndIndex):
    # getting index of the end node or end depot
    start_depot_index = routing.Start(vehicleId - data.iterStartIndex)
    timeDimension.SlackVar(start_depot_index).SetRange(0, 0)
    # timeDimension.SlackVar(end_depot_index).SetRange(0, 0)
logging.info("added waiting time and end time constraint")
return timeDimension

'''
'''
def createCtForTimeWindows(data, routing, manager, timeDimension):
"""Adds time window constraints for orders."""
dummyOrdersStartIndex = data.order.numOfNodes - data.order.numOfDummyNodes

for locationIndex in range(data.order.numOfNodes):
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(locationIndex)
    # if (routing.IsStart(index)) or (routing.IsEnd(index)) or (
    #         locationIndex >= dummyOrdersStartIndex):
    #     continue
    if index == constants.END_DEPOT_INDEX:
        continue
    if (routing.IsStart(index)) or (
            locationIndex >= dummyOrdersStartIndex):
        continue
    timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
        data.order.minEntryTimeList[locationIndex],
        data.order.maxEntryTimeList[locationIndex])
    # routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(timeDimension.CumulVar(index))
logging.info("added time window constraints")

'''
'''
def createCtForStartTime(data, routing, timeDimension):
"""Adds constraints for start time of vehicles."""
for vehicleId in range(data.iterStartIndex, data.iterEndIndex):
    index = routing.Start(vehicleId - data.iterStartIndex)
    timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
        data.vehicle.minStartTimeList[vehicleId],
        data.vehicle.maxStartTimeList[vehicleId])

logging.info("added start time constraints")

'''
'''
def createCtForCapacity2(data, routing, demandCallBackIndex):
"""Adds capacity (volume) constraints for vehicles."""
capacity2List = \
    data.vehicle.volCapacityList[data.iterStartIndex:data.iterEndIndex]

if data.parameters.performMilkRuns:
    slack = max(capacity2List)
else:
    slack = 0

routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(demandCallBackIndex, slack,
                                        capacity2List, True,
                                        constants.CAPACITY2_DIMENSION)

capacity2Dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(
    constants.CAPACITY2_DIMENSION)
logging.info("added capacity2 constraints")
return capacity2Dimension

'''
'''
def createCtForVolAtDepot(routing, manager,data, totalCapacity2Dimension, deliveryCapacity2Dimension):
"""Equalizes vol at depot for total and delivery dimensions"""
for vehicle_id in range(data.iterEndIndex - data.iterStartIndex):
index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
routing.solver().Add(
deliveryCapacity2Dimension.CumulVar(index) == totalCapacity2Dimension.CumulVar(index))
logging.info("constraint to equalize volume at depot for total and delivery dimensions ")
'''
def createCtForDummyWarehouses(data, routing, manager, capacityDimension,
capacity2Dimension, timeDimension):
"""Adds constraints for dummy orders where capacities are reset."""
dummyOrdersStartIndex = data.order.numOfNodes - data.order.numOfDummyNodes
maxWaiting = data.parameters.maxWaiting

for i in range(data.order.numOfNodes):
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(i)
    # if (routing.IsStart(index)) or (routing.IsEnd(index)):
    #     continue
    if (index == constants.END_DEPOT_INDEX):
        continue
    # if i denotes order node
    if (i < data.vehicle.numOfDepots) or (i < dummyOrdersStartIndex):
        capacityDimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(0)
        capacity2Dimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(0)
        timeDimension.SlackVar(index).SetRange(0, maxWaiting)

    # for depot nodes
    if i < data.vehicle.numOfDepots:
        timeDimension.SlackVar(index).SetRange(0, 0)

    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        capacityDimension.CumulVar(index))
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        capacity2Dimension.CumulVar(index))

logging.info("setting slack to 0 for non dummy nodes")

'''
'''
def createCtForDummyWarehousesWithPickupAndDel(data, routing, manager, totalCapacityDimension, totalCapacity2Dimension,
deliveryCapacityDimension, deliveryCapacity2Dimension, timeDimension):
"""Adds constraints for dummy orders where capacities are reset."""

dummyOrdersStartIndex = data.order.numOfNodes - data.order.numOfDummyNodes
maxWaiting = data.parameters.maxWaiting

for i in range(data.order.numOfNodes):
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(i)
# if (routing.IsStart(index)) or (routing.IsEnd(index)):
# continue
    if index == constants.END_DEPOT_INDEX:
        continue
    """i < data.vehicle.numOfDepots: This condition checks if the value of i is less than the number of depots in your routing model.
       i < dummyOrdersStartIndex: This condition checks if i is less than the index where dummy orders start."""
# if i denotes order node
    if (i < data.vehicle.numOfDepots) or (i < dummyOrdersStartIndex):
    # if i >= data.vehicle.numOfDepots and i < dummyOrdersStartIndex :
        totalCapacityDimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(0)
        totalCapacity2Dimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(0)
        deliveryCapacityDimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(0)
        deliveryCapacity2Dimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(0)

    timeDimension.SlackVar(index).SetRange(0, maxWaiting)

    # for depot nodes
    if i < data.vehicle.numOfDepots:
        timeDimension.SlackVar(index).SetRange(0, 0)

    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        totalCapacityDimension.CumulVar(index)) # cumulative weight capacity (pickup+delivery) at a specific index
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        totalCapacity2Dimension.CumulVar(index)) # cumulative volume capacity (pickup+delivery) at a specific index
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        deliveryCapacityDimension.CumulVar(index))
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        deliveryCapacity2Dimension.CumulVar(index))

logging.info(
    "setting slack to 0 for non dummy nodes with both pickup and delivery case"
)

'''
Problem: I'm expecting one vehicle to pickup and deliver as much as possible to serve the demand volume within maximum working hours. Its only picking one demand if the demand volume is near to vehicle capacity. I want to return the vehicle in the depot, then reset the capacity to 0 and then go for another pickup.
Above what I have done. Can you guide me what is the issue?? Why single vehicle not picking multiple vehicles??
